# Python Regex: How to match the string and then modify that string by adding something at the end

Tags: json, python-3.x, regex

UPDATED CODE: It is working but now the problem is that the code is attaching same random_value to every Path.

Following is my code with a sample chunk of text. I want to read Path and it's value then add (/some unique random alphabet and number combination) at the end of every Path value without changing the already existed value. For example I want the Path to be like
"Path" : "already existed value/1A" e.t.c something like that.
I am unable to make the exact regex pattern of replacing it.
Any help would be appreciated.

It can be done by json parse but the requirement of the task is to do it via REGEX.

```
from io import StringIO
import re
import string
import random

reader = StringIO("""{
    "Bounds": [
        {
            "HasClip": true,
            "Lang": "no",
            "Page": 0,
            "Path": "//Document/Sect[2]/Aside/P",
            "Text": "Potsdam, den 9. Juni 2021 ",
            "TextSize": 12.0
        }
    ],
    
},
{
    "Bounds": [
        {
            "HasClip": true,
            "Lang": "de",
            "Page": 0,
            "Path": "//Document/Sect[3]/P[4]",
            "Text": "this is some text ",
            "TextSize": 9.0,
        }
    ],
}""")

def id_generator(size=3, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

text = reader.read()
random_value = id_generator()
pattern = r'"Path": "(.*?)"'
replacement = '"Path": "\\1/'+random_value+'"' 
text = re.sub(pattern, replacement, text)
#This is working but it is only attaching one same random_value on every Path

print(text)
```

Comment: Why do you not parse the JSON string using the `json` module?

Comment: The requirement of this task is to solve it via REGEX and read it as text.

Answer (score 2):

Use group `1` in the replacement:

```
replacement = '"Path": "\\1/1A"'
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/is5S99).

The replacement regex `\1` puts back what was captured in group `1` of the match via `(.*?)`.

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful. I have upvoted it. However, how can I make every path unique. I have added a random value generator (please refer to the code I updated the code) but it is adding the same random value at the end of every Path.

Comment: You can’t do that in one command, you would need a loop. Also, this answer answers the original question (and you should accept this answer if it best answers it), but you have changed the nature of the question, thus invalidating all comments and answers, so please rollback your edits and instead ask a new question, that uses this code as the starting point, and that includes your new additional requirements.

Comment: The answer was helpful but it does not answer the complete question. The nature of my question did not change with updates. I only updated the code not the question. The code update was to make it clear and helpful for other.  Not to INVALIDATE all the comments. My original question already mentions adding "UNIQUE" alphanumeric combination at the end of every Path. This requirement remains the same in all updates, which are there to make it more clear and helpful.

Comment: @Aqsa_Nazir I disagree. The title is the key, which is “How to match the string and then modify that string by adding something at the end”, not “ How to match the string and then modify that string by adding something **unique for each replacement** at the end”.

Comment: That's your understating, however the title cannot contain all the information and requirements. That's why Stackoverflow has the option to describe the question in the body section and also write the code and the output e.t.c. In the body section I have mentioned the UNIQUE part which completes it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a json structure, maybe it would help to use the json module to parse it.

```py
import json
myDict = json.loads("your json string / variable here")
# now myDict is a dictionary that you can use to loop/read/edit/modify and you can then export myDict as json.
```

Comment: This is just a little chunk of json file as my json file is not that properly structured, that is why I am reading it as text and the real problem I am having here is finding the proper REGEX pattern for reading and modifying the Path value.